# Com server build using Python on 64-bit Windows 7 machine

Tags: python, 64-bit, py2exe, pywin32

> Original post is here:
>   http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2010-December/011011.html
>
> I am using:
>
> - OS: 64 bit Windows 7 Professional
> - Python: python-2.7.1.amd64
> - Python win32 extensions: pywin32-214.win-amd64-py2.7
> - Py2exe: py2exe-0.6.9.win64-py2.7.amd64

I am trying to build icon overlay for Windows. It has worked fine on 32 bit
Windows but not working on 64 bit Windows 7.

Here are the Python modules I have created for testing:

1. test_icon_overlay.py: ( http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/attachments/20101229/bb8c78a4/attachment-0002.obj ) com server created in Python for icon overlay which
   adds check mark overlay icon(C:\icons\test.ico) on "C:\icons" folder
2. setup_VI.py: ( http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/attachments/20101229/bb8c78a4/attachment-0003.obj ) setup file which creates test_icon_overlay.dll for
   distribution.
3. icons.zip: ( http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/attachments/20101229/bb8c78a4/attachment-0001.zip ) for testing you should extract icons.zip inside C:\

Icon overlay appears on `C:\icons` folder when I execute `python
test_icon_overlay.py` on Windows command prompt and restarts `explorer.exe`.
But its not working with the dll file created using `setup_VI.py`

I have created dll file using `python setup_VI.py py2exe` and then tried to
register it using `regsvr32 test_icon_overlay.dll`. Registration fails with
windows error message `Error 0x80040201 while registering shell extension`.

Then I turned on logger in `Python27/Lib/site-packages/py2exe/boot_com_servers.py` and here is the traceback which I am getting in `comerror.txt` on `regsvr32
test_icon_overlay.dll`

```
PATH is ['C:\\root\\avalon\\module\\sync\\python\\src\\dist\\library.zip']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "boot_com_servers.py", line 37, in <module>
pywintypes.error: (126, 'GetModuleFileName', 'The specified module could not
be found.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'DllRegisterServer' is not defined
```

Looks like there might be a problem with `win32api.GetModuleFileName(sys.frozendllhandle)` or with the dll build on 64-bit Windows 7.

Also, I saw that installation of `pywin32-214.win-amd64-py2.7` on 64-bit Windows 7 finish with the error message: [Snapshot](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/attachments/20101231/816a2063/attachment-0001.png)

```
close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

Is there anything which I am doing wrong? Any help on this is highly
appreciated.

Comment: When you say it works on 32-bit Windows, is that the 32-bit Windows 7 or an older version like Windows XP? If you haven't tried a 32-bit version of the same OS where 64-bit doesn't work then the problem may not be the 64-bitness at all. For example, if it works in XP but not Win7 then it could be UAC related.

Comment: I have tested dll generated on 32-bit Windows XP on 32-bit Windows XP, Vista and Win7 and icon overlay works fine on each OS. But 64-bit dll generated on 64-bit Windows XP/Win7 did not worked at all on 64-bit XP/Win7 machine. Registration of dll failed on 64-bit machine.

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but when executing regsvr32 the cmd window is being run with admin privileges, right?

Comment: I have tried on Win7 using Administrator account and command prompt was invoked with Admin privileges.

Comment: There is a slightly simpler setup here with same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619701/python-64-bit-dll-com-server-registration-problem-on-64-bit-windows-7

Comment: It seems like `test_icon_overlay.exe /reg` successfully registers this, but I am not sure if it is doing the right thing. Maybe a workaround...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a bug in py2exe on 64 bit Python. The sys.frozendllhandle, initialized by py2exe, is invalid such that win32api.GetModuleFileName(sys.frozendllhandle) fails.

You might want to try the patched py2exe installers at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#py2exe

Comment: Where can I see the actual patch to py2exe?

Comment: I submitted the patch to https://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3152707&group_id=15583&atid=115583